# How to use interface for nested functions

Tags: typescript

I don't know how to set the correct topic for my question, so if someone has a better name, please edit me :)

The subject is:

I have 2 functions that use the same interface:

```
interface createMailInterface {
  to: String,
  subject: String,
  message: String
}

const createMail = (config: createMailInterface) => {
  const {to, subject, message} = config
  const mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.MAIL_USER_NAME,
    to,
    subject,
    message
  }

  return mailOptions
}


const sendMail = (config: createMailInterface): void => {

  transporter.sendMail( createMail(config), (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      logger.error(error)
    } else {
      logger.info(`Email sent: ${info.response}`)
    }
  })
}
```

But in declaration on `sendMail` function I have a warning like:

> Argument of type '{ from: string | undefined; to: String; subject: String; message: String; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Options'.

in place: `createMail(config)`

So my question is, how can I use the same interface for nested functions like in the example above?

Comment: Isn't it because that your `createMailInterface ` is lacking a `from` property but `mailOptions` object is having a `from` prop?

Comment: Unrelated but I also thing you'll want to use "string" not "String". string is the type, String is an interface

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `transporter.sendMail` method has it's own interface defined called 'Options'. You can see the type definition by command/control clicking on the `transporter.sendMail` method.

I'm guessing the interface is something like this.

```
interface Options {
from: string
to: string
subject: string
}
```

In your case, your "from" variable can be string or undefined because `process.env.MAIL_USER_NAME` can theoretically be undefined, so you can have an

```
if(process.env.MAIL_USER_NAME){
 ** Run code here **
}
```

or an

```
if(!process.env.MAIL_USER_NAME){
** Handle your error **
}
```

To make sure it is never undefined, for the "to" and "subject" variables, just change your "String" in your interface to "string".